# How to play more video on the same player with Vimeo player.js

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-player

I'm trying to play videos one after the other in the same Vimeo player, without success.
This is the code I'm working on. I can't find any example on how to do that.
I'm sure I'm wrong but I don't know how to go further...

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.main-player');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
var video_ids = ['123456789', '987654321'];
video_ids.forEach(function(item, index) {
    player.pause();
    player.loadVideo(item);
    player.on('loaded', function() {
        player.play();
    });
})
```

Comment: It looks like you're playing a video, then immediately pausing it and loading the next video, repeatedly. You'll have to arrange to wait for the current video to end before moving on to the next. (The Vimeo player library emits an `ended` event.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, because can't test it right now , but you can try something like this:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.main-player');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
var video_ids = ['123456789', '987654321'];
var index = 0;
var playNext = function(data){
    player.pause();
    if(index<=video_ids.length)
       player.loadVideo(video_ids[index++])
}
player.pause();
player.loadVideo(video_ids[index++]);
player.on('loaded', function() {
    player.play();
});

player.on('ended', playNext);
```

Comment: Can you please give a help also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857210/how-to-use-setcurrenttime-on-vimeo-video-within-a-playlist

Answer (score 1):

The idea is pretty simple by listen to the `ended` event then moving to the next item.

First of all, we just create a class to hold some information such as the list & current playing index:

```js
import Player from "@vimeo/player";

class Playlist {
  constructor(playlist) {
    this.playlist = playlist;
    this.currentIdx = 0;
  }

  init() {
    this.player = new Player("app", {
      id: this.currentItem,
      width: 640
    });

    this.player.on("ended", this.onEnded.bind(this));
  }

  onEnded() {
    if (this.currentIdx < this.playlist.length) {
      this.currentIdx++;

      const nextId = this.currentItem;
      this.player.loadVideo(nextId);

      // Check next item has loaded then play it automatically
      // you might not receive any error in case of having to interact with document
      this.player.on("loaded", () => {
        this.player.play();
      });
    }
  }

  get currentItem() {
    return this.playlist[this.currentIdx];
  }
}

// Try to run 2 items
const pl = new Playlist([59777392, 28582484]);
pl.init();
```

NOTE: I also created a `codesandbox` link for you here https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-firefly-ej0fd?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857210/how-to-use-setcurrenttime-on-vimeo-video-within-a-playlist thank you.