# How to use setCurrentTime() on vimeo video within a playlist?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to set the current time for the last video in the playlist, but it always fails.
This is the code I'm working on with my try.
It doesn't set the time at all and I don't know how to solve.

```
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.main-player');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    var video_ids = [123456789, 987654321, 543216789];

    var index = 0;
    var playNext = function(data) {

        if (index <= video_ids.length)
            player.loadVideo(video_ids[index++])

    }

    let last = video_ids.length - 1;

    player.loadVideo(video_ids[index++]);
    player.on('loaded', function() {

        if (last == index++) {
             player.setCurrentTime(200);
        }
        player.play();

    });

    player.on('ended', playNext);
```

Comment: I don’t think `if (last == index++)` makes much sense here to begin with - the `loaded` event will presumably also fire, if the user skips _backwards_ in the playlist. You should rather check which ID the currently playing video has at this point.

Comment: I've already created an example which was pretty clean and different from above code. Anyway I've just tried based on my example before and it works fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-firefly-ej0fd?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @tmhao2005 your solution is perfect but I need to run it on the iframe and when I try with the div#app in your example I have problems with private video and oembed... is there a way to adapt your solution to work with an iframe?

Comment: I switched to use IFRAME but it seems to be working fine. You can check about link again

Comment: @tmhao2005 I can't manage to use your script with my code, maybe for the bundler you are using (parcel) that I've never used...